# LC_date like option for excel sheet (possible in libre office)

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, paste

Windows 8.1, office 2013, english interface - danish region.

When working in excel I often paste dates from another application. These dates are in the form `Januar 2013`. When pasting, it seems excel automatically recognizes this as a date, and converts the value to `01-01-2013` and a displayed value of `Jan-2013`

But for some months, e.g. may (which in danish is spelled 'Maj'), excel does not recognize the text. In this case  `Maj 2012`is displayed as such - and not converted to a date value.

I am aware of [this ansvar](https://superuser.com/a/408476/71658) - but in my case I need to copy the values with first saving as csv and then importing. Also [changing to a custom format after pasting](https://superuser.com/a/629033/71658) doesn't work either.

Is there anyway I can change the regional settings per sheets?

---

**EDIT:** Libre office can do what I need :-) See below.

This is my office excel settings[image: word setings]

It works in libre office (the text is recognized as dates):

This is my Libre Office calc settings[image: libre office calc setings]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date data you need to 'replace' is in A1 downwards. Just put :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"November","November"),"Oktober","October"),"September","September"),"August","August"),"Juli","July"),"Juni","June"),"Maj","May"),"April","April"),"Marts","March"),"Februar","February"),"Januar","January")
```

in B1, then drag downwards. Hoep it helps. ( :